# METEOR: Error invoking Method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following error:

> the function "saveCalEvent" is not found on the server

but I did write it.

Why do I get:

> Error invoking Method 'saveCalEvent': Method not found [404]

even if I did write the method server-side?

Here is my code:

```js
CalEvent = new Mongo.Collection('callevent');
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.main.rendered = function(){
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view){
        var calendarEvent = {};
        calendarEvent.start = date;
        calendarEvent.end = date;
        calendarEvent.titel = 'New Event';
        calendarEvent.owner = Meteor.userId;
        Meteor.call('saveCalEvent', calendarEvent);
      }
    })
  }
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.methods({
      'saveCalEvent' : function(ce){
         CalEvent.insert(ce);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: i found out in console that mongo is not known. console says:


 (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { CalEvent = new Mongo.Coll
 |                                                                   ^
ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined

Comment: Are you on the last version of Meteor, and is this package code or classic (inside `client` or `server` or `lib`...) code?

Comment: file system:

projekt/client/projekt.js

Comment: ah thanks a lot. it doesnt work cause its in client folder. i droped the projekt.js in the projekt folder and it works

Comment: i have one more question. i write it a new topic because here is not possible to make n1 texts.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly, or delete it, since in its current form it can not be properly answered.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor handles some directories differently. A list of special folders and their scope is listed [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

Server code stored within the client folder will not be visible to the server and is therefore dead code.

Special directories are:

- client
- client/compatibility
- server
- public
- private
- tests